# Duplicate identity code in SQL for vb.net winforms

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

Good day,

I am not too sure about the reason this can happen.

I have a large code in which I insert some values to some SQL tables. The program is working in 4-5 separate machines that access the same SQL data base that is held in another server.

```
Try : codfact = CInt(Me.CFTableAdapter.codigoQuery) + 1 : Catch ex As Exception : codfact = 1 : End Try
```

There I get my new id of the table and save it in codfact.
CFTableAdapter.codigoQuery = It is a SELECT that gets the MAX(id) of my table.

And then I do the insert:

```
While Not exit4
  Try
     Me.CFTableAdapter.InsertQuery(codfact, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, Me.codcom, 0, False, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, selprop)
     exit4 = True
  Catch ex As Exception
     If ex.Message.Contains("PRIMARY KEY") Then
        Try : codfact = CInt(Me.CF.codigoQuery) + 1 : Catch : codfact = 1 : End Try
     Else
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End
     End If
  End Try
End While
```

That is the code. 
What happens is that sometimes both programs keep working with the same codfact that should be the Unique identity ID in the SQL table.

When I try to reproduce this error I always get the "PRIMARY KEY" error and it gets the next codfact to work with(the correct way).

That codfact is used in other tables as Foreing Key. That way I get a single codfact line instead of 2 or 3.

Comment: I assume that you are getting the MAX(id) and adding 1 to it to generate your primary key....this is not the best way to approach this.  You should set the column up to auto-increment, and let SQL take care of this for you.

Comment: That might be a problem since we are using all the tables this way. I wonder what the reason could be.